# Make nodes without making a package

Tags: ros, build-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple question. Can I create a node (in C++ or Python) without the need to make a whole package? It may be a really dumb question but was really curious.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212061/make-nodes-without-making-a-package/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2015-06-24

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do it, but it is very impractical.

Take a look at [this](http://jbohren.com/tutorials/2014-02-10-roscpp-hello-world/#create-the-simplest-ros-c-program) tutorial for a cpp example. Also, for python you can just create a .py file, import rospy, do your ROS stuff and run it. But watch out for dependency issues.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamnItROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/24967/damnitros/) on 2015-11-01**:
That's exactly what I'm looking for. Many Thanks.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-05-03**:
Link is broken, what was it linked to? @Gary Servin

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2017-08-08**:
Fixed the link